# Visual Studio 2017 quick actions remove internal

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a question about VS2017 quick actions. How can i remove the internal tag from the auto generated property with quick actions ?

[image: screenshot showing internal set]

Answer (score 1):

Close your VS and navigate to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#
```

Look for a file named `prop.snippet`

Open the file with any text editor i.e. notepad

Look for the following line of code:

```
<Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[public $type$ $property$ { get; internal set; }$end$]]>
```

and change it to:

```
<Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[public $type$ $property$ { get; set; }$end$]]>
```

Please note this will effect every instance of VS. A better approach would be to create your own code snippet and import it in.

Please refer to **[Walkthrough: Create a code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2017)** for more info on creating custom code snippets.

Comment: you are wrong. The prop.snippet is used when you type in the editor prop and press tab twice. I dont think that quick actions are using these snippets

Answer (score 0):

In another way, you can use code snippets to create another template.